# Applications look ugly when using third-party "Arc OSX themes"

Tags: themes, gtk

I'm using elementary OS Loki 0.4 with the [Arc OSX themes](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Arc-OSX-themes?content=175536) for GTK+ but the UI in apps is very ugly, can someone help me?

[image: Ugly interface in FileZilla]

Comment: Hi Simon, would you please clarify your issue? You changed the theme but don't like it? Or you don't like the interface of FileZilla? The theme can only reach so far into a program's interface if it isn't specifically designed to match elementary OS's aesthetic, if that's what you mean

Comment: Theme is modern, but in apps (VLC and others) are buttons like buttons in Win 98 :D

Comment: Right, but if you don't like the theme you installed (and want FileZilla to look closer to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gBt6H.png)), you either need to continue customizing the theme or revert back to the defaults. Unless you have a specific question about changing an aspect of a theme (as it relates to elementary OS), the only answer can be find a new theme that you think is less ugly

Answer (score 6):

You have installed a theme which generally only applies to applications which use GTK+ 3, for example all default apps in elementary.

There are other toolkits used by developers for Linux apps where GTK+ themes will not be applied at all or at least differently. Here is a (non comprehensive) list of toolkits and notable examples of apps using them:

- **XUL** is used by Firefox and Thunderbird
- **Qt** is by used by VLC and apps from the KDE project
- **wxWidgets** is used by FileZilla
- **VCL** is used by LibreOffice
- **GTK+ 2** is generally used by older apps and its themes are not compatible with GTK+ 3 themes

---

[QGtkStyle](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#QGtkStyle) (link for general info, might not apply to elementary) imitates the look of GTK+ 2 themes in Qt apps.

I'm not really sure, but I believe the way the FileZilla version available in Loki is compiled, it also tries to imitate the given GTK+ 2 theme. So in order for the app to look better, you have to find an appropriate GTK+ 2 theme and install it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `gtk2-engines-pixbuf` and moving the Ark-OSX folder to `/usr/share/themes` if it isn’t saved there yet, that fixed it for me.

Comment: This is the answer (!) to my similar question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1538704/gtk2-widgets-have-pointy-corners-dark-shadow-w95-style/1538733#1538733 Thank you! I think this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

According to the README.md of the arc theme you need to also install the gtk2-engines-murrine package.

https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme

Quote:

```
For the theme to function properly, install the following

GNOME Shell, GTK 3.14 - 3.22
The gnome-themes-standard package
The murrine engine. This has different names depending on your distro.

     gtk-engine-murrine (Arch Linux)
     gtk2-engines-murrine (Debian, Ubuntu, elementary OS)
     gtk-murrine-engine (Fedora)
     gtk2-engine-murrine (openSUSE)
     gtk-engines-murrine (Gentoo)
```